# SQL Server Calculate Daily Values from Accumulated Column with Interval Logging

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a power meter that log power consumption with interval of 5 mins. The daily power consumption is accumulated.

Column name of power consumption is 'Wh_1_R'

When I try to do group by date with max - min value, the data between 11:55pm and 00:00am the next day will be lost.

Any other method to include the 5 minutes data in the same day calculation?

[image]

My current query:

```
select 
   CONVERT(varchar, Datetime, 111) As Date, 
   'KMN3FLK_11' As DPM, 
   'R3' As Line, 
   'Machine' As Category, 
   Max(Wh_1_R) - Min(Wh_1_R) As Active_P,  
   Max(Varh_1_R) - Min(Varh_1_R) As Reactive_P, 
   Max(P_Total) As Max_Power, 
   Min(P_Total) as Min_Power,
   Max(Q_Total) As Max_QPower, 
   Min(Q_Total) as Min_QPower
From [dbo].[KMN3FLK_11]
Where Wh_1_R <> 0
group by CONVERT(varchar, Datetime, 111)
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The expected results are as my query above, current my Active_P column indicates the Max(Wh_1_R) - Min(Wh_1_R), while this result will omit the data from 11:55pm to 00:00am. I would like to include those as well. Please advise

Comment: Well why are you grouping by conversion to varchar, just group it by the datetime?

Comment: I want to know daily consumption.. conversion is to convert datetime to date. Else if i group by datetime I wont be able to get daily value

Comment: @JenasTan, to make it clear - do you want to inlude the rows with time value `23:55:00` as part of the calculation for two different days?

Comment: @Zhorov Thank you for ur reply. Not only to include 23:55:00 data, but also the consumption between 23:55:00 and new day 00:00:00. If I use max - min, I would lost this 5 minutes of data as the logging interval is 5 minutes. THe optimum way is to use the min value of the next day, minus the min of the day to get the daily value, but Im not sure can we use the value of another group with group by function. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your sample data has to do with the question -- given that the question is about one column and the sample data has zillions (and is hard to read as well).

But the solution to your problem is to get the consumption at the beginning of each day and use window functions.  Given that the values are cumulative, aggregation with `min()` works:

```
select convert(date, datetime) as dte,
       min(Wh_1_R) as first_consumption,
       (lead(min(Wh_1_R)) over (order by min(datetime)) - 
        min(Wh_1_R)
       ) as daily_consumption
from [dbo].[KMN3FLK_11]
group by convert(date, datetime)
order by min(datetime);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I have tried ur query, i have got the actual value of the day, one issue being I will get a NULL value for today consumption as tmr data was not logged. Anyway to tackle this? Please advise.

Comment: @JenasTan . . . If there are no logs on a given day, then the date wouldn't appear in the result set.  I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may try to "double" the rows within this 5-minutes interval using an `APPLY` operator. The following simplified example demonstrates this apporach:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO KMN3FLK_11
FROM (VALUES
   (CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-13T00:00:00'), 141111),
   (CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-12T23:55:00'), 141121),
   (CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-12T00:00:00'), 141131),
   (CONVERT(datetime, '2021-01-11T23:55:00'), 141141)
) v ([Datetime], Wh_1_R)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(date, a.[Datetime]) As [Datetime], 
   'KMN3FLK_11' As DPM, 
   'R3' As Line, 
   'Machine' As Category, 
   MAX(k.Wh_1_R) - MIN(k.Wh_1_R) AS Active_P
FROM KMN3FLK_11 k
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   (k.[Datetime]),
   (
   CASE 
      WHEN DATEDIFF(day, k.[Datetime], DATEADD(minute, 5, k.[Datetime])) = 1 
      THEN DATEADD(minute, 5, k.[Datetime]) 
   END
   )
) a ([Datetime])
WHERE (a.[Datetime] IS NOT NULL) AND (k.Wh_1_R <> 0)
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, a.[Datetime])
```

Result:

```
Datetime    DPM Line    Category    Active_P
--------------------------------------------
2021-01-11  KMN3FLK_11  R3  Machine 0
2021-01-12  KMN3FLK_11  R3  Machine 20
2021-01-13  KMN3FLK_11  R3  Machine 10
```